# Tablespace consumed by views

Tags: oracle, view, tablespaces

I was in an SQL class where the instructor said "DBAs don't like it when users create views, because they will clobber tablespace."

Obviously, I understand that any schema object will consume *some* tablespace, but isn't it a huge exaggeration to say that views will eat up tablespace, since all you need to store is just a query (and privileges and some other metadata), and as such they won't take significantly more space than an ordinary row in an ordinary table?

Comment: That is why he is an instructor and not an actual DBA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not true, unless they meant "materialised views"

- [ORAFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tablespace)

> Permanent tablespaces are used to store user data and user created objects like tables, indexes and materialized views.

Comment: Correct, but even if the instructor meant Materialized View the statement would still be incorrect.  I'm sure you would agree that a DBA wouldn't dislike Materialized Views simply because they take space.  There are times when a MV should be used and the space it requires is completely justified.

Comment: @Leigh Riffel: can you clarify please? An indexed view in SQL Server consumes space on disk

Comment: Huh?  The question is tagged Oracle not SQL Server.  Your answer is correct in the sense that a materialized view could use a significant amount of space, whereas a view would not.  I was just pointing out that even if the instructor meant MV his statement would still have been incorrect because a DBA would be fine with a user creating a materialized view if it was necessary for the application regardless of how much space it consumed.  Does that help?